# Creating wedge buffers from many point to one in QGIS

Tags: qgis, buffer, polygon-creation

I have two point layers. One point layer has many random points which are start points. The second point layer has only one point which is the endpoint.

I want to create wedge buffers from the start points layer to the endpoint layer.

Something like this:

[image]

All buffers have same parameters only angle degree is different.

Comment: Can you please add which software do you have in mind to solve this?

Comment: I want solve this in QGIS

Comment: What is the coordinate system of data, projected(meter, inch) or geographic(lat long)?

Comment: Coordinate sysyem is Wgs84 and metric

Comment: Do you mean azimuth by angle?

Comment: Yes this can be also azimuth

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- Open "Create Wedge Buffer" tool. Select the layer containing the start points as input layer.
- Click "Data defined override" option ([image]) near the "Azimuth" and select "Edit.."
- Use this expression: (`'end'`: the layer name of the end point)

  ```sql
  degrees( azimuth( $geometry, geometry( get_feature_by_id( 'end', 1 ))))
  ```

[image]